# CSS page footer does not fit

Tags: footer

please check this link. All div are closed properly and could not understand whats wrong with footer width where as home page is correct.

thanks a lot. u saved my time

Comment: Remove `#footer{ width: 640px; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have class

```
#footer
{
    width:640px;
    clear:both;
    color:#999999;
    text-align:center;
    width:640px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 85%;
}
```

where you set footer width to 640px (two times). For ex. remove width declaration.